# How do i read json from an post input in Xquery code?

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

I am sending the below POST data to an XQuery module.
When I try to read it, I have tried everything, `fn:doc`, `from-json`, etc...., I cannot find a solution. Depending of what I try to do, I either get coercion error or data is not a string.

Can anyone help me put the `Artist` value to an `$artist` variable, etc...?

Here is the post request:

> curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -g  "http://localhost:8030/LATEST/resources/jsontest/" -d "{"Artist" :"bowie","Weeks" : {"gte" :"1960-01-01","lte" :"2020-12-31"},"Genres":"","Released":"" }"*

and here is my code reading the POST request:

```
declare function test:post(
    $context as map:map,
    $params  as map:map,
    $input   as document-node()*
) as document-node()*
{
  xdmp:log($input)
};
```

and the result is this:

```
{"Artist":"bowie", "Weeks":{"gte":"1960-01-01", "lte":"2020-12-31"}, "Genres":"", "Released":""}
```

which looks like a json document (to my untrained eye), but i can't figure out how to "read/assign" the value for Artist (in this case "bowie") and put it in a variable.

- I tried `fn:doc`, because I thought it should be a `document-node`
- I tried `let $artist := $input/Artist/data()`, but get a coercion error
- I tried many other option (`from-json`, etc..)

but I always wind up with some sort of error

how can I get access to the values in the JSON? I've been running around in circles through the MarkLogic documentation and different searches and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The subtle differences between a `document-node()`, a JSON object, a JSON document stored in the database as an `object-node()`, and a string of JSON can be confusing. Especially when if you log it and see the stringified representation, you just see the JSON and it is difficult to tell what it really was.

When in doubt, [`xdmp:describe()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:describe) and [`xdmp:type()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:type) can be helpful for that. They can help tell you what sort of "thing" you really have.

When the method interface says you will get a `document-node()`, that is a generic container for stuff. It will have a child `node()`, but that node could be lots of things. It could be an XML document and the children could be comments, processing instructions, element, or it could be a `binary()`, `text()`, or a `json:object`. In this case, you know that you are going to have a JSON object.

You can use XPath to select that child node:

```
$json := $input/node()
```

With a JSON Object, you can access the `Artist` property by using [`map:get()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/map:get)

```
let $artist := map:get($json, "Artist")
```

The difference between a JSON `object` and an `object-node()` (JSON document stored in the database within MarkLogic) is that a regular JSON Object is just a data structure, but the `object-node()` lives in the database and has been parsed and saved as database nodes tied to indexes, so there are extra features and functionality. After inserting a JSON object into the database, if you later retrieve it with `fn:doc()`, then you it will be a JSON `object-node()` in the database, and you can do some neat things such as use XPath against it.

[`xdmp:from-json-string()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:from-json-string) can be used to parse a JSON string. It will construct a JSON object (which is basically a specialized `map`).

You can convert that `object-node()` into a JSON object using [`xdmp:from-json()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:from-json).

It is also possible to serialize the `json:object` map as an XML structure using [`json:transform-from-json()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/json:transform-from-json) and then transform that XML structure back into a `json:object` using [`json:transform-to-json()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/json:transform-from-json).

Comment: thanks for the help, but it doesn't work, when i do as you suggest, i get the follwoing error:

{"errorResponse":{"statusCode":500, "status":"Internal Server Error", "messageCode":"INTERNAL ERROR", "message":"XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) xdmp:from-json-string(document{object-node{\"Artist\":text{\"bowie\"}, \"Weeks\":object-node{\"gte\":text{\"...\"}, ...}, ...}}) -- arg1 is not of type xs:string . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail."}}

i seem to understand that what $input is, is a document, but no matter what i try, i don't come inside to read the values

Comment: thanks, but i am still lost,
I tried doing the xdmp:describe() and xdmp:type() 
and tried also $json := $input/node()
and they all return this error

Invalid coercion: object-node{\"Artist\":text{\"bowie\"}, \"Weeks\":object-node{\"gte\":text{\"1960-01-01\"}, ...}, ...} as document-node() . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail."}}

when i try the map options, it gives me:
"message":"XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) map:get(object-node{\"Artist\":text{\"bowie\"}, \"Weeks\":object-node{\"gte\":text{\"1960-01-01\"}, ...}, ...}, \"Artist\") -- arg1 is not of type map:map

Comment: If you are returning a value, you need to ensure that you return a `document-node()`, not an `object-node()` - or you can return an empty sequence. The return type of that function is `document-node()*`. So, either return `$input`, or `()`, or wrap whatever structure you want in `document { $myCustomStuff }`

Comment: ok, thanks you, that did it, wrapping in a document.

Strange because i have another function returning a document and that problem never happened.
But it works, that's all that matters, thanks!